# RSA Cryptography in Python

Tags: python, rsa

I wanted to try out the RSA encryption function in Python but my script is not working in pyCharm. Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong? The random.sample and random.choice are giving a problem I believe...

```
from functools import *
import _random

def inverse(e,m):
    return filter(lambda d: e*d % m == 1, range(1, m))[0]

def sift(toRemove, numList):
    '''Takes a number, toRemove, and a list of numbers, numList.
    Returns the list of those numbers in numList that are not multiples of toRemove.'''

    return list(filter(lambda x: x % toRemove != 0, numList))

def primeSieve(numberList):
    '''Returns the list of all primes in numberList, using a prime sieve algorithm.'''
    if numberList == []:      # if the list is empty,
        return []             # ...we're done
    else:
        prime = numberList[0]  # The first element is prime!
        return [prime] + primeSieve(sift(prime, numberList[1:]))

def makeEncoderDecoder():

    p, q = _random.sample(primeSieve(list(range(2, 10))), 2)
    n = p*q
    m = (p-1)*(q-1)
    print("Maximum number that can be encrypted is", n-1)

    e = _random.choice(primeSieve(list(range(2, m))))
    if m / e == 0:
        print ("Please try again")
        return
    else:
        d = inverse(e, m)
        encoder = lambda x: (x**e)
        decoder = lambda y: (y**d)
        return [encoder, decoder]
```

Comment: There is no rsa encryption function in python

Comment: Any advance on *”not working”*? Give a [mcve].

Comment: This is what I get in Python.                                                                Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/svendebacker/Documents/RSA encoder/RSA encoder.py", line 38, in <module>
    makeEncoderDecoder()
  File "/Users/svendebacker/Documents/RSA encoder/RSA encoder.py", line 23, in makeEncoderDecoder
    p, q = _random.sample(primeSieve(list(range(2, 10))), 2)
AttributeError: module '_random' has no attribute 'sample'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Import random Remove _random try just random do this inside your function .

Comment: And what don't you understand from the message? `dir(_random)` will tell you that it indeed doesn't have a `sample` attribute.